# Aligning long Equations

Tags: equations, align

How could I align the expression `[F_{1}(M)\cdot L_{M+1}]_{ij}` with the rest of the equations?
This is the code I am using:

```
\begin{align*}
[F_{1}(M)\cdot L_{M+1}]_{ij} \\
&=\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\prob(\gamma(M+1)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+1))=s|X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i)\cdot\\
&\prob(\gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j|X(0)=M+1,\phi(0)=s)\\
&=\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\prob(\gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+1))=s,\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j|X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i)\\
&= \prob(\gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j|X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i) = [F_{1}(M+1)]_{ij}
\end{align*}
```

The output is like in the attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd use something like this

[image]

Note I changed your conditional `|`'s to `\mid`'s to give them better spacing. The normal `|` kinda drowns

**Edit:** Missed the `\cdot`, this is exactly why one never ends a displayed line with a relation or a binary, it gets overlooked.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand\prob{\mathbb{P}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \MoveEqLeft[3] [F_{1}(M)\cdot L_{M+1}]_{ij} 
  \\
  = {} &\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\prob(\gamma(M+1)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+1))=s\mid X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i)
  \\
& \cdot  \prob(\gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j\mid X(0)=M+1,\phi(0)=s)
  \\
  = {} &\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\prob(\gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+1))=s,\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j \mid X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i)
  \\
  = {} & \prob(\gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j\mid X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i) = [F_{1}(M+1)]_{ij}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the third row needs to be right-indented relative to the second row.

Comment: @Mico Might be I missed the `\cdot` which should of course never be at the end of a line

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot to accompany the code; feel free to revert.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion.

[image]

Observe that I've replaced all four instances of `|` with `\bigm\vert` and manually increased the sizes of the opening and closing parentheses in each line. I'd also place the final term, i.e., `[F_{1}(M+1)]^{}_{ij}`, on a new row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\prob}{\mathbb{P}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&[F_{1}(M)\cdot L_{M+1}]^{}_{ij} \\
&= \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \prob\bigl( \gamma(M+1)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+1))=s
   \bigm\vert X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i\bigr)\\
& \qquad\times \prob\bigl( \gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j
   \bigm\vert X(0)=M+1,\phi(0)=s \bigr) \\
&= \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \prob\bigl(  \gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),
   \phi(\gamma(M+1))=s, \phi(\gamma(M+2))=j
   \bigm\vert X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i \bigr) \\
&= \prob\bigl( \gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j 
   \bigm\vert X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i \bigr) \\[\jot]
&= [F_{1}(M+1)]^{}_{ij}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is as follows. It's improved from @Mico 's solution:

1. add the indentation by `\hptantom` of the first line of the equations;
2. add the indentation by `\hptantom` of the third line of the equations;
3. use `\left` and `\right` instead of `\bigl` and `\bigr` before parenthesis;
4. use `\mid` instead of `\bigm\vert`;
5. delete `[\jot]` codes of the sixth line of the equations;
6. add the dot `.` at the end of the last line of equations.

Welcome others to improve the current solution furthermore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\prob}{\mathbb{P}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\hphantom{=~}[F_{1}(M)\cdot L_{M+1}]^{}_{ij} \\
&= \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \prob\left(\gamma(M+1)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+1))=s
   \mid X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i\right)\\
&\hphantom{=\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}}\times \prob\left(\gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j
   \mid X(0)=M+1,\phi(0)=s \right) \\
&= \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \prob\left(\gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),
   \phi(\gamma(M+1))=s, \phi(\gamma(M+2))=j
   \mid X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i \right) \\
&= \prob\left(\gamma(M+2)<\gamma(0),\phi(\gamma(M+2))=j 
   \mid X(0)=1,\phi(0)=i \right) \\
&= [F_{1}(M+1)]^{}_{ij}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it might be useful if you stated explicitly what the "improvements" are... :-)

Comment: @Mico I revised the statements.

Comment: Thanks. I'd question whether #3 is an improvement, as the `\left` and `\right` directives don't do anything useful: The associated parentheses are at the basic size (hence: why bother with the `\left` and `\right` directives?), while the spacing between `\prob` and the opening parentheses is now messed up. There normally shouldn't be a space between math-op and math-open objects; cf. `\sin(\alpha)` and `\log(2)`. #4 is a measure to stay consistent with #3. #5 is an aesthetic choice, and one shouldn't argue about tastes, right? Same for #1. #6 appears to be a deviation from the OP's setup.